# Mysql transaction for transferring credit between users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions, innodb

I have a simple power system as users can borrow to each other:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO power (sender, receiver, amount)
    VALUES ('$sender', '$receiver', '$amount')");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET power=power-$amount WHERE user_id='$sender'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET power=power+$amount WHERE user_id='$receiver'");
```

I check if the sender has enough credit to transfer by a `SELECT` query before running the above-mentioned set of queries.

**Issues 1:** I think, it is better to put all these four queries into a `Transaction`; as InnoDB ACID will guarantee a safer performance. What will be the best transaction to do so?

**Issue 2:** power is `unsigned int`. If by any chance (even unlikely), user does not have enough credit `power-$amount` will not set 0; instead it will be cycled through the largest value of int(), which is 4294967295. This means that the user will be granted almost unlimited power (credit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't bother with this:

> I check if the sender has enough credit to transfer by a SELECT query before running the above-mentioned set of queries.

That leaves you open to a race condition that you'll have to deal with anyway. Instead, set up constraints in your database to make it impossible to get into an invalid state.

> **Issue 2**: power is `unsigned int`.

Don't do that either, there's no need. A 4 byte signed integer should have more than enough space on the positive side; if it doesn't, you can switch to a signed 8 byte integer. The reason you want a signed value is that it makes integrity checking fairly easy: if a balance drops below zero then something is wrong. If you use an unsigned value, you'd have to reserve `4294967295-n` (for some `n`) to detect underflow and overflow instead of a simple `< 0`.

As far as constraining your data is concerned, normally you'd use a CHECK constraint like this:

```
check (power >= 0)
```

but MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraints. However, you can write a BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE trigger that can check that `new.power >= 0` and [raise an exception](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html) if it isn't.

Now you have a `users` table that doesn't allow invalid `power` values so we're done with issue 2.

On to issue 1: transactions. Yes, you absolutely do want to use a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) for the transfer. You'll want a sequence like this:

1. `start transaction`
2. `INSERT INTO power (sender, receiver, amount) VALUES ('$sender', '$receiver', '$amount')`
3. `UPDATE users SET power=power-$amount WHERE user_id='$sender'`
4. `UPDATE users SET power=power+$amount WHERE user_id='$receiver'`
5. Have there been any errors from the "check trigger"?

   - If there have then send a `rollback` to the database and tell the user what went wrong.
   - If there haven't then send a `commit` to the database.

The transaction will ensure that all three operations will either succeed or fail as a single unit and the CHECK constraint (implemented as a trigger) ensures that no one can give away more power than they have.

Comment: @Ali: Cool, that's why we're all here :)